# Getting Google search results with JSoup

Tags: java, jsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to get a list of Google search results via JSoup. The method I'm currently using works perfectly fine for the first page (n), but for n+1 pages it does not work so well. Here is how I'm getting the first page:

```
doc = Jsoup.connect(search).userAgent("Chrome").get();
links = doc.getElementsByClass("r");
```

The search string would contain something like: `https://www.google.com/search?q=apple` for the first page. Then my code looks like this for n+1 pages:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= pages; i++){
    search = "https://www.google.com/#q=" + keyword + "&start=" + (i*10);
    doc = Jsoup.connect(search).userAgent("Mozilla").get();
    links.addAll(doc.getElementsByClass("r"));
}
```

The search for n+1 pages would look something like:`https://www.google.com/#q=apple&start=10`. 
The main issue that I'm having is that `doc.getElementsByClass("r")` in the n+1 searches contains no elements. This means that the class `r` does not exist in what JSoup returns. I verified this by searching through `doc.toString()`. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: I'd suggest you don't parse the search results, but instead use an API.

Comment: @Kayaman which one ?

Comment: @Kayaman Also, for the purposes of my research I would like to not use an API. Any suggestions on how to just parse the HTML?

Comment: JSoup is already parsing the HTML. You're just not happy with the results it's giving you. Try using something else than the `r` class to access the results.

Comment: You can use selenium webdriver for achieving your goal.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class googleResults {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("search" + Keys.ENTER);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        printResults(driver);
    }

    public static void printResults(WebDriver driver) {
        List<WebElement> searchResults = driver.findElements(By.className("r"));
        for (WebElement searchResult : searchResults) {
            System.out.println(searchResult.getText());
        }
        driver.findElement(By.id("pnnext")).click();
        /*Limit number of calls*/
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        printResults(driver);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is asked for JSoup, not selenium.